# numpy array casting ruled not 'safe'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, casting

Indexing one numpy array with another - both are defined as dtype='uint32'. Using numpy.take to index and get an unsafe casting error. Not come across this before. Any idea what is going on?

```
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:13:35) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.9.0'

>>> a = numpy.array([9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1], dtype=numpy.uint32)
>>> b = numpy.array([1, 3], dtype=numpy.uint32)
>>> c = a.take(b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    c = a.take(b)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('uint32') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: I get no warning running python 3.4.3 64-bit and numpy '1.9.2rc1'

Comment: I think is the problem is with assigning to `a.take(b)` to `c`. Try setting `c =numpy.array(0,dtype=numpy.uint32)` before `c = a.take(b)`

Comment: No warning either here with Python 2.7.5 64-bit and numpy 1.9.1.

Comment: Updated to numpy 1.9.2 but still the same error. Setting c=numpy.array(0, dtype=numpy.uint32) doesn't work either. Same result on Windows 32-bit XP and Windows 8.1. Weird!

Comment: I would interpret this problem as follows. NumPy uses signed ints for indexing (since `a[-1]` works like it would in a Python list, after all). When it sees that the index array has the wrong dtype, it tries to convert the index array to an array of signed ints (which would be reasonable and produce reasonable results if `b` were an array of, say, `int16`). Since this conversion isn't safe for an array of `uint32` - for example, a maximal `uint32` value would become -1, a rather different index - NumPy throws an error. You may want to convert the dtype of `b` yourself before using `take`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is quite common when working NumPy functions that require indexes or lengths to be specified (it's not just `take`, see for example [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4384)).

The problem is that, for indexing purposes, NumPy would like to treat your `uint32` array as an `int32` array (which is probably the "pointer" integer type on your 32 bit system, [`np.intp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)) and wants to cast it down to that type.

It can't do this safely - some of the integers in an unsigned array might not be representable as a signed 32 bit integer. The error you see reflects this.

This means that you'll get the same error if `b` has dtype `int64` or a float dtype, but not if it is `int32` or a smaller integer dtype.

For what it's worth, this isn't an immediate problem for the indexing notation `a[b]` which allows the unsafe casting (but will raise an error if the index is out of bounds). Try for example `a[2**31]` - NumPy casts to `int32` but then complains that the index `-2147483648` is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks! I normally use a[b] but that is supposed to be slower than .take. Anyway, will stick to what works!

Comment: It isn't slower anymore in 1.9.x. And this behavior should probably be reported as a bug, `np.take` should do the same that indexing does: use unsafe casting once it has confirmed that the index is an integer, e.g. on a 32 bit system `a[2**32-1]` returns `a[-1]`, because the `2**32-1` gets converted to a `np.uint32` which is then unsafely cast to a `np.int32`. This corner case buggy behavior is less annoying than making `np.uint32` unusable as an index.

Comment: @Jaime Good to hear that the a[b] type of indexing is no longer slow. I'll drop a note on the numpy mailing list about np.take. Thanks!